# Python Developed criss cross game - Adding random input feature

Tags: python

I am working on a project. I developed a criss-cross game. Now I want to add a feature to it. I want to play against the computer. The code works fine if you want to play with 2 player inputs. Now, player1 gives one input and player2 gives another input. Everything works well here. My aim is; player1 gives an input then the computer gives the player2's input randomly. I tried some random input codes but did not work well. There is a list at the top of the code.

```
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The player1 gives input '1' so the board list became;

```
board = ['X', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to add a feature to player2, when player1 gives an input player2 section gives a random input from the board. But, it has to select the numbers from the list so player1 plays again and goes like this.

```
import random


def game():
    board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    end = False
    winning = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))

    def draw():
        print(board[0], board[1], board[2])
        print(board[3], board[4], board[5])
        print(board[6], board[7], board[8])
        print()

    def player_1():
        n = loc()
        if board[n] == "X" or board[n] == "O":
            print("\nWrong number")
            player_1()
        else:
            board[n] = "X"

    def player2():
      #  random_num = random.choice(board)
      #  n = loc(random_num)
        n =loc()
        print(n)
        if board[n] == "X" or board[n] == "O":
            print("\nWrong number")
            player2()
        else:
            board[n] = "O"
            print(board)

    def loc():
        while True:
            while True:
                a = input()
                try:
                    a = int(a)
                    a -= 1
                    if a in range(0, 9):
                        return a
                    else:
                        print("\nWrong number, 1-9")
                        continue
                except ValueError:
                    print("\nWrong number, 1-9")
                    continue

    def check():
        count = 0
        for a in winning:
            if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == "X":
                print("Win: Player 1\n")
                return True

            if board[a[0]] == board[a[1]] == board[a[2]] == "O":
                print("Win: Player 2\n")
                return True
        for a in range(9):
            if board[a] == "X" or board[a] == "O":
                count += 1
            if count == 9:
                print("Game Over\n")
                return True

    while not end:
        draw()
        end = check()
        if end == True:
            break
        print("Player 1:")
        player_1()
        print()
        draw()
        end = check()
        if end == True:
            break
        print("Player 2:")
        player2()
        print()


game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive solution is to keep generating random board index until you generate one that is not taken (not `X` or `O`) and assign it.

```
def artificial_player():
    while True:
        position = random.randint(0, len(board)-1)
        if board[position] != 'X' and board[position] != 'O':
            break
            
    board[position] = 'O'
```

Now you can change the call to `player2()` with the `artificial_player()`.

A better solution would be to keep track of "empty" board positions and randomly choose from these, instead of just blindly trying. The problem is that your code is quite messy and hard to update without breaking. I would suggest you to keep view and application logic separate.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your approach is very good.